# Map elements from a Array to another Array

Tags: java

```
//UtenteDto class 
package it.links.corsoditco.dto;

import java.util.Date;

public class UtenteDto {
   
   public UtenteDto(String nome, String cognome, String nomeCompleto, String localita, String indirizzo, String civico, int cap, String numeroCell, Date dataNascita) {
       this.nome = nome;
       this.cognome = cognome;
       this.cap = cap;
       this.civico = civico;
       this.nomeCompleto = nomeCompleto;
       this.localita = localita;
       this.indirizzo = indirizzo;
       this.numeroCell = numeroCell;
       this.dataNascita = dataNascita;
   }
   
   private String nome;
   private String cognome;
   private String nomeCompleto;
   private String localita;
   private String indirizzo;
   private String civico;
   private int cap;
   private String numeroCell;
   private Date dataNascita;
   
   public String getNome() {
       return nome;
   }
   public void setNome(String nome) {
       this.nome = nome;
   }
   public String getCognome() {
       return cognome;
   }
   public void setCognome(String cognome) {
       this.cognome = cognome;
   }
   public String getNomeCompleto() {
       return nomeCompleto;
   }
   public void setNomeCompleto(String nomeCompleto) {
       this.nomeCompleto = nomeCompleto;
   }
   public String getLocalita() {
       return localita;
   }
   public void setLocalita(String localita) {
       this.localita = localita;
   }
   public String getIndirizzo() {
       return indirizzo;
   }
   public void setIndirizzo(String indirizzo) {
       this.indirizzo = indirizzo;
   }
   public String getCivico() {
       return civico;
   }
   public void setCivico(String civico) {
       this.civico = civico;
   }
   public int getCap() {
       return cap;
   }
   public void setCap(int cap) {
       this.cap = cap;
   }
   public String getNumeroCell() {
       return numeroCell;
   }
   public void setNumeroCell(String numeroCell) {
       this.numeroCell = numeroCell;
   }
   public Date getDataNascita() {
       return dataNascita;
   }
   public void setDataNascita(Date dataNascita) {
       this.dataNascita = dataNascita;
   }
   
}
```

```
//CredenzialiUtenteDto class
package it.links.corsoditco.dto;

public class CredenzialiUtenteDto {

    public CredenzialiUtenteDto(String username, String password) {
        this.password = password;
        this.username = username;
    }
    
    private String username; 
    private String password;
    
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    
}
```

```
// class where I insert elements in the Array (only user and pass)
public class CredenzialiLookup {
public CredenzialiUtenteDto[] setArrayCredenziali() {
        //popola  una array di credenziali
        CredenzialiUtenteDto[] arrayCredenzialiUtenteDto = new CredenzialiUtenteDto[16];
        
        arrayCredenzialiUtenteDto[0] = new CredenzialiUtenteDto("Pinco_Pallino", "12345");
        arrayCredenzialiUtenteDto[1] = new CredenzialiUtenteDto("Tizio_Caio", "98745");
return arrayCredenzialiUtenteDto
}
```

*and i have another list :

```
// Class where I insert the Users (with full information)
public class UtenteLookup {
public UtenteDto[] setArrayUtente() {
       UtenteDto[] arrayUtenti = new UtenteDto[16];
       arrayUtenti[0] = new UtenteDto("Pinco", "Pallino" , "Pinco_Pallino" , "Nowhere" , "ViaMare" , "86", 73044, "327179372", null);
       arrayUtenti[1] = new UtenteDto("Tizio", "Caio" , "Tizio_Caio" , "Milano" , "ViaVai" , "86", 73044, "327179372", null);
return arrayUtenti;
}
```

- 

I already have a method check() in my main class , this method iter trough a loop while he match a corrispondence with my String inputUsername = "Pinco_Pallino".
and now I want to map this element of arrayCredenzialiUtenteDto  to the matched element of arrayUtenti  in another object called CredenzialiUtenteRelazione (relation of the 2 objects)

I want to know how i can write a method in CredenzialiUtenteRelazione , the return is a Utente Object.
*

example

```
public class UtenteCredenzialiRelazione {
    CredenzialiUtenteDto[] credlst = new CredenzialiLookup().setArrayCredenziali();
    UtenteDto[] utentelst = new UtenteLookup().setArrayUtente();
    
public UtenteCredenzialiRelazione(CredenzialiUtenteDto[] credlst , UtenteDto[] utentelst ) {
        ???
}
    
    
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand your code, could you provide the full classes? And additionally: Never ever write code in your own language except it's English :D it's just bad style and makes it harder for people like me to understand

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [Pairs](https://www.baeldung.com/java-pairs).
They allow you to associate two object with one another.